# Best way to extract MAC address from ifconfig's output?

Tags: regex, linux, command-line-interface

What is the best way to extract the MAC address from `ifconfig`'s output?

Sample output:

```
bash-3.00# ifconfig eth0        
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1F:2E:19:10:3B:52    
          inet addr:127.0.0.66  Bcast:127.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0    
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          ....
          ....
```

Should I use cut, [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) or anything else, and what are the merits and demerits of one method over the other.

Comment: Which one is mac address?

Comment: @Nabin: the "HWaddr" field.

Answer (score 119):

You can do a cat under `/sys/class/`

```
cat /sys/class/net/*/address
```

Specifically for `eth0`

```
cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address
```

Comment: This gives all addresses, not just for eth0, for example.

Comment: Iin openwrt cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address works a treat: "cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address" gives "c2:ee:1e:08:e6:39"  Note eth0 links you to the hardware specific location:"cd /sys/class/net/eth0/" changes the cwd to "/sys/devices/platform/ag71xx.0/net/eth0/"

Comment: To store in a variable: `MacAdd=\`cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address\``.

Answer (score 74):

I would use:

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'
```

The -o will cause grep to only print the part of the line that matches the expression.  `[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}` will match 1 or 2 hexidecimal digits (Solaris doesn't output leading zeros).

Comment: What?  This will match regardless of placement of the MAC address whereas the other solutions will not.

Comment: It does have the advantage of also working on OSX since that ifconfig use 'ether' instead of 'HWaddr'

Comment: That was my intention, I have worked with plenty of different Unixes and this is the only solution that will work on all of them.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, my original thought was that it's over-engineered for the job but it works and is better on slightly different output (I'd want to put it in a script so I don't have to remember the regex).

Comment: That 'grep -o' is a handy addition to my knowledge as well.

Comment: Are there any UNICES that don't output leading zeros for the MAC sections (necessitating "{1,2}" instead of "{2}")?

Comment: This is the best way I've seen. That's because this command will be useful not only with ifconfig but with any other source of MAC as could be extracting the MACS of Xen DomU with xm network-list the MACS of the ARP caché, etc

Comment: I have used `ifconfig eth0 | grep -Eo '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}[:-]){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}' | head -n1` to compensate for devices that contain '-' instead of ':' and/or report more than 6 bytes.

Answer (score 25):

I like using /sbin/ip for these kind of tasks, because it is far easier to parse:

```
$ ip link show eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:30:21:48 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

You can trivially get the mac address from this output with awk:

```
$ ip link show eth0 | awk '/ether/ {print $2}'
00:0c:29:30:21:48
```

If you want to put a little more effort in, and parse more data out, I recommend using the -online argument to the ip command, which will let you treat every line as a new device:

```
$ ip -o link 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue \    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000\    link/ether 00:0c:29:30:21:48 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000\    link/ether 00:0c:29:30:21:52 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 100\    link/[65534] 
5: sit0: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop \    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Not all distros ship `/sbin/ip`, which belongs to the `iproute2` package.  But this is the best solution: ip is much nicer than ifconfig!

Answer (score 10):

Not sure whether there really are any advantages, but you can simply use awk:

```
ifconfig eth0 | awk '/HWaddr/ {print $5}'
```

Comment: Use `ip addr` instead of ifconfig.  `ip addr | grep -C1 "link/ether"` should do.

Answer (score 4):

Since the OP's example refers to Bash, here's a way to extract fields such as HWaddr without the use of additional tools:

```
x=$(ifconfig eth0) && x=${x#*HWaddr } && echo ${x%% *}
```

In the 1st step this assigns the ouput of ifconfig to x. The 2nd step removes everything before "HWaddr ". In the final step everything after " " (the space behind the MAC) is removed.

Reference: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu/Debian

```
ifconfig | grep HW | awk '{print $5}'
```

For Rhat or CentOs try

```
ip add | grep link/ether | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the method described here (with slight modification): http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_do_i_figure_out_my_ip_address_on_a_mac.html

```
ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | cut -d " " -f2
```

Which you can then alias to a short 'myip' command for future use:

```
echo "alias myip=\"ifconfig | grep 'inet ' | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | cut -d ' ' -f2\"" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this one:

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep -Eo ..\(\:..\){5}
```

or more specifically

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep -Eo [:0-9A-F:]{2}\(\:[:0-9A-F:]{2}\){5}
```

and also a simple one

```
ifconfig eth0 | head -n1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f5`
```

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 14.04 in terminal

```
ifconfig | grep HW
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ifconfig en1 | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'
```

- Replace "en1" with the name of the nic card "eth0" or remove altogether "en1" - easy and useful solution.

Answer (score 0):

Note: on OS X eth0 may not work. Use p2p0:

```
ifconfig p2p0 | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'
```

Comment: interface on my mac server is en0 , so p2p0 doesn't work always

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Mac OS X:

```
ifconfig en0 | grep -Eo ..\(\:..\){5}
```

So does:

```
ifconfig en0 | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'
```

Both are variations of examples above.

Answer (score 0):

```
ifconfig | grep -i hwaddr | cut -d ' ' -f11
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice and quick one:

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep HWaddr | cut -d ' ' -f 11
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to get MAC address of the active adapter, so ended up using this command.

```
ifconfig -a | awk '/^[a-z]/ { iface=$1; mac=$NF; next } /inet addr:/ { print mac }' | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

ifconfig en0 | grep ether    - for wired mac address

ifconfig en1 | grep ether    - for wireless mac address

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep -o -E ..:..:..:..:..:..
```

instead of `eth0` you can write the interface you need it's mac address

Answer (score -1):

Output of ifconfig:

```
$ifconfig

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1b:fc:72:84:12
      inet addr:172.16.1.13  Bcast:172.16.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::21b:fcff:fe72:8412/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:638661 errors:0 dropped:20 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:93858 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:2
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:101655955 (101.6 MB)  TX bytes:42802760 (42.8 MB)
      Memory:dffc0000-e0000000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:3796 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3796 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:517624 (517.6 KB)  TX bytes:517624 (517.6 KB)
```

The best way to extract MAC address is:

```
ifconfig | sed '1,1!d' | sed 's/.*HWaddr //' | sed 's/\ .*//' | sed -e 's/:/-/g' > mac_address
```

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep HWaddr
```

or

```
ifconfig eth0 |grep HWaddr
```

This will pull just the MAC address and nothing else.

You can change your MAC address to whatever you want:

```
ifconfig eth0 down,
ifconfig eth0 hw ether (new MAC address),
ifconfig eth0 up
```

Comment: HW, HWaddr is not an option for some Linux/Unix systems, and it will show nothing.